# Copy data between two columns using where with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id | one  | two
1  | aa   |
2  | da   |
3  | sds  |
4  | as   |
5  | dfss |
6  | r    |
7  | fd   |
```

How can i make copy all data from "one" to "two", where length one == 2 with SQL? In this example should be:

```
id | one  | two
1  | aa   | aa
2  | da   | da
3  | sds  |
4  | as   | as
5  | dfss |
6  | r    |
7  | fd   | fd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, I think:

```
UPDATE table SET two = one WHERE LENGTH(one) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE your_table SET two = one WHERE LENGTH(one) = 2
```